# Disabling FloatingActionButton after list view and showing a message that the limit is exceeded

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

How can I disable a button, in this case a `FAB(Floating Action Button)`, and prevent the user adding more items to the list because he is exceeding the limit and showing a message? I'm using a `FutureBuilder` and a `ListView.builder`, after the user adds 3 item to the list, I want to disable the FAB and prevent the user to add more items to the list and showing some sort of notification/message/floating over button message to the user that he is exceeding the limit of 3 items per list. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/add_items_screen.dart';
import 'components/items_list.dart';

class ItemScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'item_screen';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.grey[600],
        ),
      ),
/// I want to disable this button after the limit of 3 items in the list view
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              isScrollControlled: true,
              builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: AddItemScreen(),
                  )));
        },
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            color: Colors.grey[100],
            child: Container(
              height: 800,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Item List Display',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
/// Here is where the items are rendered as a list
                        Expanded(child: ItemList()),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Item list component:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'common/api/api_caller.dart';
import 'utilities/item_api_helper.dart';
import 'models/item.dart';
import 'stores/item_store.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemList createState() => _ItemList();
}

class _ItemList extends State<ItemList> {
  Future<HTTPResponse<List<ItemData>>> _getItemList() async {
    var _itemData = await APICaller.instance.getItems();
    var provider = Provider.of<ItemDatStore>(context, listen: false);

    provider.setItemList(_itemData.data, notify: false);

    return _itemData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<HTTPResponse<List<ItemData>>>(
          future: _getItemList(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Consumer<ItemDataStore>(
                builder: (context, itemData, child) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: itemData.itemList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      ItemData items =
                          itemData.getItemByIndex(index);
                      return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Text('items.title'),
                  ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried using an `if` statement where I can define `if(itemData.itemList.length <3)` it should return those three items, `else {Text('Item limit of 3 is exceeded')}` but I'm not sure if this is the right way or if I defined it right since I put it in the `Item List` component and I need to put it in the `Item Screen`. Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your Floating action button with Visibility it hides and not woking anymore :)

```
Visibility(
            visible: items.length > 3,
            child : FAB here,

          ),
```

Comment: This works thanks, but how to notify the user that the button is disabled due to limit exceeded?

Comment: You can notify showing some count down numbers inside or outside your fab.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the FAB like this

```
onPressed: items.length < 3? addItemToList : null;
```

and addItemToList is

```
 void addItemToList(){
     // Do Something here
 }
```